# How i can move redux action to separate file

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

In my test app reducers moved to separate files, but I understand that actions should be also moved to separate files .What is the action here? And  how i can move it to separate file

```
const initalState = {};

export const GET_REQUEST = "GET_REQUEST";

export default function iteams(state = initalState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_REQUEST:
      return { ...state, ...action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export const GetCommitsAndMembersDataAction = (payload) => ({
  type: GET_REQUEST,
  payload,
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file named `actions.js` inside the same folder (or anywhere else in you `src`)

put this line and other actions inside it, these are the actions :

```
    export const GetCommitsAndMembersDataAction = (payload) => ({
  type: GET_REQUEST,
  payload,
});
```

Now add this line at the top of any `.js` file you want to use it:

```
import {GetCommitsAndMembersDataAction} from "./actions" // path depends on where your are importing it
```